# HLS stream and save Partially - Swift

Tags: ios, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am streaming m3u8 url in an iOS application.
I am referring [Apple HLS Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HLSCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application.
I could stream and add offline the url.
Also playing from the offline is possible.

Is it possible to stream and save the video partially (eg:- user trying to stop the video, I need to save up the user cancelled part)

Comment: get the player current time on when you stop, once its resume use seekonTime: playerCurrentSavedtime

Comment: @ThreeCoins:  is it possible to save the streamed videos on some user action. As mentioned in the apple documentation when cancel the streaming it will not save the file. Any possible way to achieve this with out cancel.